# How can I fill empty ID cells with the IDs from either one of two other DataFrames

Tags: python

I have the following table in which some (but not all) user IDs are missing:

| user ID | item ID | item type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 123 | question |
| NaN | 126 | answer |
| 14 | 129 | question |

To get the missing user IDs I want to look up the corresponding item ID in the following two tables (depending on whether the item type is a question or an answer in the table above).

answer DataFrame:

| item ID | user ID |
| --- | --- |
| 126 | 12 |

question DataFrame:

| item ID | user ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 |
| 129 | 14 |

Finally, I want to get something like this:

| user ID | item ID | item type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 123 | question |
| 12 | 126 | answer |
| 14 | 129 | question |

Comment: Can you have the same item ID in both question and answer dataframes? For example, can 126 be in both?

Comment: Yes the same item ID can be in both answer and question dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df["user ID"].isnull() & df["item type"].eq("question"),
              df["user ID"].isnull() & df["item type"].eq("answer")]

choices = [df["item ID"].map(dict(zip(question["item ID"],question["user ID"]))),
           df["item ID"].map(dict(zip(answer["item ID"],question["user ID"])))]

df["user ID"] = np.select(conditions, choices, df["user ID"])

>>> df
   user ID  item ID item type
0     10.0      123  question
1     10.0      126    answer
2     14.0      129  question
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a np.where() and a merge to get the data you need

```
df['user ID'] = df['user ID'].fillna(0).astype(int)

df_final = pd.merge(left = df, right = answer_df, on = 'item ID', how = 'outer', suffixes = ('', '_right'))
df_final['user ID'] = np.where(df_final['user ID'] == 0, df_final['user ID_right'], df_final['user ID']).astype(int)
df_final[['user ID', 'item ID', 'item type']]
```